# Exponentially distributed probability at the post office

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, exponential-distribution

Consider a post office that is run by two clerks. Suppose that when you enter
the system you discover that Olsen is being served by one of the clerks and
Nelson by the other. Suppose also that you are told that your service will
begin as soon as either Olsen or Nelsen leaves. If the amount of time that
the clerks serving Olsen ans Nelson are exponentially distributed with mean
1/λ1 and 1/λ2, what is the probability that, of the three customers, you are the last to leave the post office?

I conditioned: P(you last) = P(Olsen finished first) $\times$ P(Nelson finishes before you) + P(Nelson finished first)$\times$ P(Olsen finished before you).

This means $\frac{λ1}{λ1 + λ2}$ $\times$ $\frac{λ2}{λ1 + λ2}$ + $\frac{λ2}{λ1 + λ2}$ $\times$ $\frac{λ1}{λ1 + λ2}$ = $\frac{2λ1λ2}{(λ1 + λ2)^2}$.

I think I got that right, but what if you want to know what the probability of Olsen being the last to leave the post office? Or Nelson? Both $\frac{1}{λ1 \timesλ2}$?

Comment: This is simpler if the two rates of service are equal. Then you have probability 1/2 of being last. By the no-memory property, the contest between you and whoever else is still being served starts over, and with equal rates you have a 50:50 chance of being last. // That is consistent with your first answer (with equal rates). I'm not exactly sure what you are computing for your second answer, but that answer does not seem consistent with the equal rate solution.

Comment: For the second and third answer, I want to know what the probability is that Olsen is the last to leave the post office? And the probability that Nelson is the last to leave the post office?

Comment: If $\lambda_1 \ne \lambda_2,$ then the one of them at the slower server is more likely to leave last.

Comment: The probability that Olsen is last to leave is $$\left(\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}\right)^2$$ and the probability that Nelson is last to leave $$\left(\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}\right)^2,$$ by similar reasoning to the original question.